# Open file from external storage in Android

Tags: android, file

This could probably be a fast fix but currently I am unable to get this working...

I have an asynctask where I am parsing a XML file. If I place an XML file in the assets folder i can open and parse it no problem.

But if I try to open a XML file from external storage it fails.

Here is my asynctask:

```
private class async extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
    while (!isCancelled()) {

     try {
         NodeList nList;
         Node node;

         InputStream is = getAssets().open("file.xml");
         // this works

         File is = new File("/storage/emulated/0/test.xml");
         // this fails

         DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
         DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
         Document doc = dBuilder.parse(is);
```

I am getting this error:

```
I/System.out: File path: /storage/emulated/0/test.xml
W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/test.xml (Permission denied)
```

These permissions are in my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Could someone tell me why I am getting this error?

Thanks!

Comment: **NEVER HARDCODE PATHS**. Your hardcoded value will be wrong on hundreds of millions of devices. Beyond that, [you may not have the permission yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it), if your `targetSdkVersion` is 23+ and you are running on Android 6.0+.

Comment: The path will not be hardcoded, this was just a test. The real absolute path will get passed through String params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see your error message :

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/test.xml
>   (Permission denied)

Remember that running on running Android 6.0 you *must implement* [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) before you try to read or write the external storage.

setting this into your manifest.xml is not enough for devices with Android 6.0+:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Ahh I totally forgot about that! You were right! Thanks :)

Comment: Got it working now. Turns out I don't even need READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE will suffice if I grant it at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

You should not hardcode the path. You can try this:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + MY_DIR_NAME + File.separator + "file.xml"
```

Comment: The path will not be hardcoded, this was just a test. The real absolute path will get passed through String params

Answer (score 1):

this is the method I use to open a pdf file from the folder that I created in the internal storage (sd card) of my phone.
but first you need to asd the user for the permission , go to manifest and write down :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and in your main activity, you must implement [runtime permissions](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting) before you try to read or write the external storage.

than use this method below don't forget to change the folder and file name

```
public void openPDF2(){
    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + "PDF folder 12"+ File.separator ;
    File file = new File(path,fileName+".pdf");

    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(Uri.fromFile(file).toString());

    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    intent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

    Uri uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(GenerateQRActivity.this, GenerateQRActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".provider", file);

    try {
        intent.setDataAndType(uri, mimeType);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);


        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "choseFile"));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG2, "openPDF2: the problem is : "+e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to access the filesystem using absolute paths.

To retrieve the path of the SD card you can use:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
```

So if you want to create a file named test.xml

```
new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"test.xml");
```